# Text stroke in <input type="text"/>

Tags: jquery, css, input, outline, stroke

I want to use text stroke in `<input type="text"/>` and I need it to be cross-browser (firefox, google chrome, safari, opera, IE7+).

Is any there any method to do it (CSS 2.1, jQuery...)?

Comment: With "text stroke" do you mean a strike-through on the text in the input?

Comment: I think everyone is misreading the intent. The believe the OP is referring to the css property `-webkit-text-stroke`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as acpeted if you got the info you want

Comment: It would be good if the user could edit the question to provide more details.

Comment: @user1109813 can you clarify if you are speaking about css property that outlines text or capturing a keystroke when the user is typing?

Comment: Hello, thank you for all answers. Ben D - I looking for outline text in input. -webkit-text-stroke do it but it work only for chrome and Safari. Here is demo: http://css-tricks.com/examples/TextStroke/ None of the solutions work for IE... For IE work progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow and progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.glow work for box not for text inside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe he's speaking about the css property text-stroke (`-webkit-text-stroke`). This is only properly supported in webkit browsers, so no proper implementation can occur in, for instance, Internet Explorer. However, you can kind of fake it with `text-shadow` which [can work in ie7+](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/06/29/full-css3-text-shadows-even-in-ie/). if you MUST have it in ie. See http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/

It would look something like:

```
.stroke_text {
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
          -1px -1px 0 #000,
          1px -1px 0 #000,
          -1px 1px 0 #000,
          1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

or for inline:

```
<input type='text' 
       style="color: white; text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000; width:200px; font-size:20px;" />
```

The only real drawback of this approach is that the shadow can only be 1px or it starts to look funny, so it's not a perfect replication of `text-stroke`. That said, you might want to look into conditional css, where browsers that support it use text-stroke, and others use this hacky approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but I think this is what you want -

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="function_you_want_tocall()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the vague question, you have many choices:

```
$('#myInput').change(function() { ... } ); // this will fire onblur if the text has changed
$('#myInput').keydown(function() { ... } ); // this will fire when a key is pressed down
$('#myInput').keyup(function() { ... } ); // this will fire when a key is released
$('#myInput').keypress(function() { ... } ); // this will fire when a printable key is pressed
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='text']").keypress(function() {
        // Your logc goes here
    });
});
```

This will bind a keypress event to every input type=text. If you want a specific ID, replace $("input[type='text'] with $("#your_id"). In addition, also play with keydown and keyup events to figure out what suits you most.